# slice 2d array in php

Tags: php, arrays, 2d

Is there a way to slice 2d array when all column are all zeros? TIA

```
$cars = array(
    array('Cars', 0, 18, 2, 4, 0, 3, 0, 8),
    array('BMW', 0, 13, 2, 4, 0, 3, 0, 8),
    array('Saab', 0, 29, 2, 4, 0, 3, 0, 8),
    array('Land Rover', 0, 15, 2, 4, 0, 3, 0, 8),
    );

 echo '<table border="1">';
 foreach ($cars as $car) {
     echo '<tr>';
     foreach ($car as $key) {
         echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
     }
     echo '</tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Can you show expected output

Comment: you want the sub-array without `0`s?

Comment: Not too sure what your asking...can you elaborate?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you want to remove 0 columns from array? can you please paste your desire output?

Comment: Did the answer not resolve your issue? Was it usefull? atleast have the curtousy to mark it and upvote it if it was.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow and I am still confused on all the features of Stackoverflow. I have dumped this code because it did not satisfy my requirements.
Xorifelse - I did try to click the up button but there is an error of 15 reputation showing. Thanks for the coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will remove the columns if every value in the column has the value `0`. If you had other plans such as slicing you still can use the code to help you identify what you want.

I do this before actually printing out the array as I do not simply know of a function to do this, so you'd have to create one.

The function `array_column()` is used to retrieve the columns and I compare it against `array_intersect()` that returns the rows with the same value and compare that against the amount of rows in your table.

```
$cols = count($cars[0]);
$rows = count($cars);
$filter = [0]; // add more unwanted values if you please

for($col=1; $col<$cols; $col++){ // skip index 0
    if(count(array_intersect(array_column($cars, $col), $filter))) == $rows){
        // We found a column "$col" where every value is "0".
        foreach($cars as $k => $arr){
            // Looping over the main array.
            unset($arr[$col]); // unset the cloned array.
            $cars[$k] = $arr;  // update the original array with new value.
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can print your table with the same code you had.